# Android: On Bluetooth Data receive method?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've just started reading about bluetooth in Android. I've done a couple of Apps but there is something I can't find.

Is there any function that is called when data is received via Bluetooth? Like a bluetooth listener with an "onDataReceived" method?

If there isn't, what is an alternative? I don't want to use a timer in order to call a function to check if there is data in the bluetooth buffer...

Comment: I had to do just that - I used a handler to check every minute to see if there was a connection still active.  The handler checked for what's in the buffer.  You should be careful to do calls to read() form the inputstream this, though, that is a blocking call and if you have no data, it will hang forever.